# How to make Coroutine sequential call

Tags: android, kotlin, async-await, kotlin-coroutines

I have a requirement after I call the local database(room) and get the data then only I will fire the network call.
If local data is present then network call will not happen otherwise network call will happen and it will store the data.
I have tried the same with a strategy class ***but network call is happening before it checks the local database.***

**DataAccessStrategy.kt**

```
fun <T, A> fetchCategory(databaseQuery: () -> LiveData<T>,
                         networkCall: suspend () -> Resource<A>,
                         saveCallResult: suspend (A) -> Unit,
                         clearDB: suspend () -> Unit): LiveData<Resource<T>> =
        liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
            emit(Resource.loading())
            val categoryList = databaseQuery().map { it ->
                Resource.success(it)

            }
            emitSource(categoryList)

            if (categoryList.value?.data == null || Preferences(MainApplication.getContext())
                            .getBooleanPreference(MainApplication.getContext(), Preferences.APP_CATEGORY_UPDATE)) {
                val networkCallStatus = networkCall()
                if (networkCallStatus.status == SUCCESS) {
                    if (Preferences(MainApplication.getContext()).getBooleanPreference(MainApplication.getContext(),
                                    Preferences.APP_CATEGORY_UPDATE)) {
                        clearDB()
                    }
                    saveCallResult(networkCallStatus.data!!)
                    Preferences(MainApplication.getContext()).storeBooleanPreference(MainApplication.getContext(),
                            Preferences.APP_CATEGORY_UPDATE, false)
                } else if (networkCallStatus.status == ERROR) {
                    emit(Resource.error(networkCallStatus.message!!))
                    emitSource(categoryList)
                }
            }

        }
```

**ProjectRepository**

```
class ProjectRepository constructor(
        private val homePagePostDAO: HomePagePostDAO,
        private val categoryDAO: CategoryDAO,
        private val homeRemoteDataSource: HomeRemoteDataSource
) {
    val TAG = "ProjectRepository"
    val getCategoryFromDB = categoryDAO.getAllCategory()

    fun getAllCategoryList() = fetchCategory(
            databaseQuery = { categoryDAO.getAllCategory() },
            networkCall = { homeRemoteDataSource.getCategory() },
            saveCallResult = { categoryDAO.insertAllCategory(it.data) },
            clearDB = { categoryDAO.deleteAllCategory() }
    )
}
```

> So the main requirement is until I get the data from the room db it
> should not execute the next line.

> I want to make a sequential call using a coroutine. That means I have
> two calls one is db select query another one is a retrofit network
> call. Retrofit network call will start only if db call is finish.

Comment: Think about a design where your viewmodel request data to your main repository. Here you have to introduce a new layer for local repository and network repository which provide data to your main repository. You main repository decided when call network repository or local data. Main repository contains information about your local db if your local data is not enough then main repository request Network repository to bring data.

Comment: Yes, I want to make a sequential call using a coroutine.